# Wireless Modem Networking

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb, modem, adsl

I want to know if is there any kind of Modem which I can buy to build a network. The modem should be wireless (WiFi) and shouldn't require electricity to work (either USB powered or Chargeable) and can network with many PCs, MACs & Linux computers at once.

I have a USB modem from some company which provides internet to us. The USB is using 3G technology to give us 3.1 MBPS of speeds. So I wonder if is there any kind of modem which can turn this single user USB to multiple user connection? May be some modem which can build network first and then allow me to connect this USB to it.

I am not sure if this can be achieved or not. Please comment on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [MiFi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MiFi) device.  (Mobile Wifi).  There are many different makes and types (I think "MiFi" is a trademark of Novatel, but other people make similar products).  Most of them are mains powered, but not all.

Some mobile phones provide "WiFi Tethering".  I use an [HTC Wildfire](http://www.htc.com/uk/product/wildfire/overview.html) which does just this.

Comment: What is Tethering?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tethering

Comment: ok is there a way I can share internet of my Laptop like Tethering with other laptops or mobiles?

Comment: I know the bluetooth and ICS way but I opt to know about WiFi way

Comment: If you are connecting to the internet through USB then you should be able to use ICS to share through WiFi (select the wifi adaptor in the ICS setup window)

Comment: Ok I need to give it a try. I am currently somewhere can't test it.

Answer (score 0):

3G? that does not sound like a modem, but a wireless adapter on a 3G network for your computer. There are plenty of USB powered modems, and there are plenty of all-in-one modem/router/wi-fi devices, but I can't seem to find any examples of a device that does both. Either way, these won't help you share that type of a connection. You will need to look at ICS (Internet Connection Sharing), a search on this site should pull up several questions and answers for various scenarios that will help you get what you want working.

Essentially, the connection would come in on the 3G USB adapter to the computer. ICS to your computer's ethernet adapter could then go to a wifi router that can do DHCP/NAT and other computers could connect to that.

Comment: You're right ICS can do the job and I am currently using it but the problem is for ICS I have to have a PC as server which I don't want. I want an independent device which can fuel all PCs with WiFi without electricity and wires.